# 555 circuit doesn't work

Tags: pcb, 555, debugging

I'm a beginner in the field of electronics, and I have been trying to put together flasher and buzzer circuits together.

[image: PCB]

[image: the schematic]

this what i did till now :D 
but when i finished the circuit on the pcb the leds doesn't blink :(

Notes on the PCB:
between BS4 and BS3 a variable Resistor

between BS6 and BS5 a Button for the flasher

between BS1 and BS2 a Button for the buzzer

can anyone help :D

Comment: Please post a schematic, your more likely to get people working on your question

Comment: i added the schematic thnx :D

Comment: Ugh, that schematic is as messy as the layout. Where are your component values.

Comment: @Tyler better than nothing

Comment: @Tyler a push button

Comment: Please add component values. What type of LED's are you using?

Comment: R1 1k

and 330 for the leds

and the variable Resistor 10k

Comment: Make sure 555 is on the blue track side. with correct pin 1 in bottom left corner.

Comment: i fix it in the PCB :D

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be self-taught by observing the voltages on each pin to see if there is a faulty connection or design or chip.

I just noticed your pin1 is a bottom view or in wrong orientation on schematic. I assume component side is blue tracks.

(I knew a professional Engineer who reversed his layout top to bottom and he went on to be a successful designer and ENG MGR of a large company)

List the pins and V readings if you get stuck and any other observations pertinent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes it is reversed but overcome that and soldered the 555 in the bottom.
no shortCirciuts.

Comment: where are the results?